# Entity Framework 7 Invalid Column Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm creating EF7 mappings for an existing database and I'm getting an "Invalid column name" error.  The code that is throwing the error is:

```
public class DepositContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<tblBatch> Batches { get; set; }
    public DbSet<tblTransaction> Transactions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<tblBatch>().HasKey(b => b.BatchID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<tblTransaction>().HasKey(t => t.TransactionID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<tblBatch>().HasMany(b => b.tblTransactions).WithOne().HasForeignKey(t => t.fBatchID);
    }
}

public class tblBatch
{
    public int BatchID { get; set; }
    public int? fDepositID { get; set; }
    public Guid BRN { get; set; }
    public string BCN { get; set; }
    public decimal? BCT { get; set; }
    public string BatchFileName { get; set; }

    public List<tblTransaction> tblTransactions { get; set; }
}

public class tblTransaction
{
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
    public string TRN { get; set; }
    public string TransactionStatus { get; set; }

    public int fBatchID { get; set; }
    public tblBatch tblBatch { get; set; }
}
```

This is throwing a `Invalid column name 'tblBatchBatchID1'.`  And when I use SQL Profiler to see what is being sent to the database, it is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[TransactionID], [t].[fBatchID], [t].[TRN], [t].[TransactionStatus], [t].[tblBatchBatchID1]
FROM [tblTransaction] AS [t]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP(1) [b].[BatchID]
    FROM [tblBatch] AS [b]
    WHERE [b].[BatchID] = @__BatchId_0
) AS [b] ON [t].[fBatchID] = [b].[BatchID]
ORDER BY [b].[BatchID]',N'@__BatchId_0 int',@__BatchId_0=37
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried setting your tblTransactions list as a virtual property? `public virtual List<tblTransaction> tblTransactions { get; set; }`

Comment: Just tried it and got the same result

Comment: Can you include which version of EF you are using? RC1, beta8, etc.

Comment: I'm using: "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"

Answer (score 2):

There were some bugs in EF RC1 that produced the wrong column name in query generation. See [this list of bugs](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%22invalid+column+name%22+is%3Aclosed) that might be related to your issue.

You can attempt to work around this by explicitly setting the column name.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<tblBatch>().Property(e => e.BatchID).HasColumnName("BatchID");
```

If you're feeling brave, you can try upgrading to RC2 nightlies of EF Core and see if the issue is fixed there.